# Spark DF processing time: why processing time drop for looping the same operation?

Tags: scala, performance, apache-spark, jvm, spark-streaming

I am trying to do a "naive measure time" (`endTime - startTime`) for some spark operations, to get an idea about different alternatives to do the same logic.

```scala
def measureElapsedTime[T](f: => T): (T, Long) = {

  val start = System.nanoTime()
  val result: T = f
  val end = System.nanoTime()

  (result, NANOSECONDS.toMillis(end - start))
}
```

**I am getting a decreasing processing time series from the loop. Why does it happen?**

Let's say, for example, I am measuring the following simple operation:

```scala
def t1(): (Array[Row], Long) = measureElapsedTime {
  val res = spark.read.json(nestedDF)
  res.collect()
}
```

Measuring it the following way:

```scala
val n = 1000
def avg(f: () => (Array[Row], Long)) = 1.to(n).map(_ => f()._2).sum / n
println(avg(t1))
```

Would give me approximately 45 ms on average.

**But, if I take a look at the head of the series, I see clearly a decrease in processing time.** For example, the measured time in ms in order of execution, for the first executions:

```
707
157
144
119
153
108
99
105
121
107
132
89
96
100
83
93
87
94
73
```

**Why does this pattern happen? Is this due to JVM warm-up time? Is this due to some spark optimization?**

I don't think that the reason is JVM warm-up time because it doesn't happen for operations not reusing the "same" DF (and anyway, I added some other operations before the previous example to warm up the JVM). For example, the following gives virtually stable running time:

```scala
def t2(): (Array[Row], Long) = measureElapsedTime {
  val res: Dataset[String] = nestedDF.map((str: String) => {
    val json: Value = ujson.read(str)
    ujson.write(json)
  })
  spark.read.json(res).collect()
}
```

Where running time series is:

```
44
141
93
92
79
78
79
84
76
80
78
77
71
71
70
71
103
74
69
72
```

Question background: **I am measuring operations for a spark structured streaming app, so I am quite sure that for each micro-batch I would get the first measured value, since every micro-batch is a new DF. However I might be wrong, and this is the reason I am asking this question.**

Thank you all.

---

Clarifications:

`nestedDF` in the examples above is a `Dataset[String]` with JSON string values.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                                                          |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"simple":  "a", "nested":  {"c1":  "a"}}                                                      |
|{"simple":  "a", "more-nested":  {"c1": {"c11": {"c111":  "a"}}}}                              |
|{"simple":  "a", "nested-with-diff-types": {"array": ["a", "b"], "obj": {"c1": {"c11":  "a"}}}}|
|{"simple":  "a", "nested-with-array":  {"c1": {"c11": ["a", "b", "c"]}}}                       |
|{"simple":  "a", "nested-with-array-with-obj-elem":  {"c1": {"c11": [{"a": "a"}, {"b": "b"}]}}}|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Could you share with us how you defined `measureElapsedTime`?

Comment: Sure. Added in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code essentially runs the following Spark code (the rest around it is just Scala) in a loop:

```scala
val res = spark.read.json(nestedDF)
res.collect()
```

#### Spark optimizations?

In order to understand whether there are optimizations that Spark is doing, let's use the `explain` method, which shows you the physical query execution plan that Spark will use. This was done in a Spark v3.3.1 spark-shell:

```scala
val nestedDF = Seq(
  """{"simple":  "a", "nested":  {"c1":  "a"}}""",
  """{"simple":  "a", "more-nested":  {"c1": {"c11": {"c111":  "a"}}}}""",
  """{"simple":  "a", "nested-with-diff-types": {"array": ["a", "b"], "obj": {"c1": {"c11":  "a"}}}}""",
  """{"simple":  "a", "nested-with-array":  {"c1": {"c11": ["a", "b", "c"]}}}""",
  """{"simple":  "a", "nested-with-array-with-obj-elem":  {"c1": {"c11": [{"a": "a"}, {"b": "b"}]}}}"""
).toDF.as[String]

val res = spark.read.json(nestedDF)

res.explain
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Scan ExistingRDD[more-nested#9,nested#10,nested-with-array#11,nested-with-array-with-obj-elem#12,nested-with-diff-types#13,simple#14]

res.collect

val res = spark.read.json(nestedDF)

res.explain
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Scan ExistingRDD[more-nested#28,nested#29,nested-with-array#30,nested-with-array-with-obj-elem#31,nested-with-diff-types#32,simple#33]

res.collect
```

##### Conclusion

As you see, the physical plan is exactly the same on the Spark level so no optimizations were done over there.

#### JVM optimizations?

The way Apache Spark turns scripts into Java bytecode is beyond what I know, but there is a way we can use our knowledge of the JVM to understand whether there are some optimizations being done.

If we're talking about code that gets executed quicker and quicker, we can more specifically look at the code cache. This is a region which stores code that the JIT compiler creates when compiling Java bytecode.

Using the `jconsole` tool (which is part of the Java 8 JDK), I monitored the code cache while running your code. I slightly adapted your `measureElapsedTime` to the following to get the absolute timestamp of the run:

```scala
def measureElapsedTime[T](f: => T): (T, Long, Long) = {
  val now = Instant.now().toEpochMilli()
  val start = System.nanoTime()
  val result: T = f
  val end = System.nanoTime()
  (result, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(end - start), now)
}
```

And made a `timeTaken` method instead of your `avg` to keep the value of each single run

```scala
def timeTaken(f: () => (Array[Row], Long, Long)) = 1.to(n).map(_ => (f()._2, f()._3))
```

Plotting the code cache utilization and the time it took to calculate runs shows the following graph:

[image]

A few remarks:

- I used a log scale for the y axis of the first graph because else the slight speedup after the first part is less visible
- The code cache graph starts before the time taken graph. This is because I started up my spark-shell before I actually started running the code

##### Conclusion

The code clearly speeds up, as you had already noticed. This speed up is strongly correlated with the extra usage of code cache. This also makes sense, as the JIT compiler does more and more work to compile your repeated code, each run will be executed more quickly.

Comment: That's an excellent and thorough answer.